# List All Joined Teams

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a website where I have the user login with Azure AD then I am trying to get a list of all of the Microsoft Teams that the user is a part of.  I'm using the GraphServiceClient, which doesn't appear to have the beta stuff in it, but I think I have worked around that see the example below and if there is a better way to do that let me know.

First when I'm creating the GraphServiceClient I'm supplying the beta endpoint to the constructor like this.

```cs
public GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient(string userId) {
 _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta", new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
  async(requestMessage) => {
   // Passing tenant ID to the sample auth provider to use as a cache key
   AccessToken = await _authProvider.GetUserAccessTokenAsync(userId);

   // Append the access token to the request
   requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);
  }));

 return _graphClient;
}
```

You will also notice that I'm storing the AccessToken because I need that later, which is why I question if there is a better way to handle this.

Then in the method that I have trying to get the list of joined Teams I'm doing the following.

```cs
public static async Task < IEnumerable < string >> GetGroups(GraphServiceClient graphClient) {
 var request = graphClient.Me.Request().GetHttpRequestMessage();
 request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri + "/joinedTeams");

 //request.RequestUri = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups");
 request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", GraphSDKHelper.AccessToken);

 request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

 try {
  var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(request);
  var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
 } catch (Exception e) {}

 //var gs = await graphClient.Me.MemberOf.Request().GetHttpRequestMessage();//.GetAsync();
 var results = new List < string > ();
 var groups = await graphClient.Groups.Request().GetAsync();
 do {
  foreach(var group in groups) {
   results.Add(group.DisplayName);
  }
  groups = await groups.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
 } while (groups.NextPageRequest != null);

 return results;
}
```

You can see that there is 2 parts to this.  The first part I'm trying to use the joined Team call, but that gives me the following error.  Then I'm just listing out all of the groups and that one is working fine.

```
Message: Authorization has been denied for this request.

Inner error
```

In portal.azure.com I have the App Registration setup and have given user.read.all Application Permissions

[image]

and also user.read.all under delegated permissions (not sure which I need to give it).

[image]

So why does this not work and if there are other things that I'm not doing correctly please let me know.

One additional note after some more testing.  The problem is really the me.  Anytime I call something with me, i.e. me/drives, etc. it errors.  I can call users[XXXXX]/drives and that works fine, but anything under me fails.

**Edited**

He is the code that creates the `GraphServiceClient`, which based on Marc's answer below might be cause of my problem of not being able to access `me`:

```cs
public GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient(string userId)
{
    _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta", new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
        async(requestMessage) =>
        {
            // Passing tenant ID to the sample auth provider to use as a cache key
            AccessToken = await _authProvider.GetUserAccessTokenAsync(userId);

            // Append the access token to the request
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);
        }));

    return _graphClient;
}

public async Task<string> GetUserAccessTokenAsync(string userId)
{
    TokenCache userTokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(userId, _memoryCache).GetCacheInstance();

    try
    {
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(_aadInstance, userTokenCache);
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(_appId, _appSecret);
        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(_graphResourceId, credential);

        return result.AccessToken;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Application permissions (aka "Client Credentials Flow"), it isn't possible to call any methods using `/me/`. The `/me/` path requires there be a user in context. This only occurs when a user has authenticated and you're using delegated permissions (aka "Authorization Grant" or "Implicit Grant" flows).

The `joinedTeams` method in particular also has a [known issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues#microsoft-teams-users-list-of-joined-teams-preview) which currently restricts it to the `me` user, effectively making Application scenarios impossible.

I'd suggest pivoting to a Authorization Grant flow with Delegated scopes and asking the user to authenticate. This will enable the `me` user context and allow you to retrieve `joinedTeams`.

As for storing the token, this isn't a good solution. Tokens are relatively short lived. Instead you should request "Offline Access" permissions. This will enable the `refresh_token` which you can store and use to retrieve a fresh `access_token` as needed.

Comment: The user is login into the application through Azure AD.  So what do I need to do to pivot the delegated permissions.  I have both checked off for the application registration already.

Comment: I edited my question to show all of the code that I use in creating the GraphServiceClient.